# How do you put a Stained Glass Block on an Armor Stand's Head?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been working on a little armor stand Harry Potter vs Voldemort scene, just for fun, and I was trying to make the part where the two spells meet.

[image: Harry Potter fighting Voldemort]

I figured out a way to do it, but I can't seem to get a red or green stained glass on the armor stand's head.

I've tried a few things.

```
/entitydata @e[type=armor_stand,r=1] {Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:stained_glass,Damage:14}]}

/entitydata @e[type=armor_stand,r=1] {Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:stained_glass 1 14}]}

/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1,Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:stained_glass,Damage:14}]}
```

All of them with the same outcome: it said it worked, but it didn't do anything. I checked and there was no invisible armor stand summoned, and there definitely wasn't any red stained glass. Can anyone figure out why this wasn't working?

Answer (score 1):

The `Equipment` list was updated in 1.9 to `ArmorItems`.

Your list also contains 4 empty brackets and then the item bracket.  This is too many.  The head slot is the 4th bracket set.  This is probably because you were working with a pre 1.9 command to start with.

You are also missing `Count` to specify quantity.

I also specified data types by following the number value by the proper letter.

These commands have been tested and work properly in 1.12.2:

```
/entitydata @e[type=armor_stand,r=1] {Invisible:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"minecraft:stained_glass",Damage:14b,Count:1b}]}

/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"minecraft:stained_glass",Damage:14b,Count:1b}]}
```

Comment: Oh ok. People really need to put more updated tutorials on the internet.

Comment: Infact, I think I'm gonna do that. I'll make a "Updated Tutorial on Armor Stands" video.

Comment: There are tutorials on the subject.  Always verify date or version of the page.  I always trust [the official wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Armor_Stand#Entity_data) and [DigMinecraft](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/summon_armorstand_chain_armor.php).  Those links both go to armor stand pages.  Official wiki is on the entity data values for the armor stand.  DigMinecraft is a tutorial on summoning an armor stand with armor.  It is because of these kinds of problems that I specified the current version above the commands in my answer.  This makes it easier on future readers.